# How to prove this simple equation in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove in Coq that:

```
convert l' + 1 + (convert l' + 1) = convert l' + convert l' + 1 + 1
```

only some parentheses is redundant and do not let me use `reflexivity` command; so what should I do?

All of the elements are `nat` (Natural) type so as `convert l'` is a function that will return a nat number and I do not want to use some powerful tactics like Omega and so on.

Comment: what about proving `n+1+(n+1)=n+n+1+1` for any `n : nat` first? it is cumbersome but it's quite straightforward if you recall what is a `nat`, i.e. a Peano number.

Comment: obvious hint: ``+`` is a commutative and associative function, maybe you could use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `omega` tactic. Just do `Require Import Omega.` at the beginning of your file and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 7):

`Omega` is very useful, as it quickly lets you continue with the more interesting parts of the proof, but when one is learning I personally find it helpful to see a "simpler" proof (the omega-generated proof terms tend to be very long and unreadable).

First note that you will need to use *associativity* and *commutativity* of `plus`.  Use Coq's search facilities to find useful lemmas. Use `_` as a wild card character. You can find lemmas that contain structures that look like associativity like this:

```
SearchAbout (_ + (_ + _)= (_ + _) + _).
```

locates five lemmas that contain, among others, this:

```
plus_assoc: forall n m p : nat, n + (m + p) = n + m + p
```

In the same way you can find the commutativity lemma with

```
SearchAbout (_ + _ = _ + _).
```

And here it is:

```
plus_comm: forall n m : nat, n + m = m + n
```

You cannot apply them directly, but instead you can use the `rewrite` tactic that lets you work on sub-parts of the terms.  I recommend that you play around with it to get a feeling for how it works.

Here is a proof of the desired lemma.

```coq
Require Import Arith.

Lemma nat_lemma: forall n, n + 1 + (n + 1) = n + n + 1 + 1.
  intro n.
  repeat rewrite <- plus_assoc.    (* n + (1 + (n + 1)) = n + (n + (1 + 1)) *)
  rewrite (plus_comm 1 (n+1)).     (* uses (1 + (n + 1) = (n + 1) + 1 *)
  repeat rewrite plus_assoc.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Now use this lemma to prove your theorem.

Comment: Wonder full . Thank you for helping

Comment: A tad shorter sequence of rewrites: `now rewrite Nat.add_shuffle1, plus_assoc.`